# How to kill apache (old gen) process

Tags: apache, server, crash, apache2

I have a webserver with  6 cpu 8gb Ram and Apache 2.4.25 / PHP7.2-Fpm on Debian 9.
When i make "service apache2 reload" all the current process scoreboard stop and go in (old gen) status. After 10/15 reload's ram is full and Apache crash, or ServerLimit is reached and Apache don't accept connections! 
Exist a solution to purge (old gen) processes?

Thx!!

Comment: Why don't you use restart instead of reload? It is more destructive, but Apache normally has no state and restarts very quickly. Otherwise it sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Restart need's 5/6 seconds, during day it's possible that i need reload configuration more than 5 times and this will generate a disruption of service. But at the moment is the only solution..

Comment: Upgrade to 2.4.29 solve the bug!

Comment: Good news. Perhaps you should answer your own question so that it is clear to others that it is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 2.4.29 solve the bug!